# Get all pairwise combinations from a list

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

For example, if the input list is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want the output to be

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

If possible, I would like a solution which is better than the brute force method of using two for loops. How do I implement this?

Comment: There are 2^n pair-wise combinations for a collection of n elements. All solutions will require an exponential amount of time to generate all combinations; a nested for-loop is going to get you within a constant factor of the fastest solution. Unless you were simply looking for something more compact.

Comment: @lungj It's been a while since I've studied math formally, but where are you getting that `2^n` figure? Ordered pairs are 4! / (4 - 2)! (== 12) and unordered pairs are 4 choose 2 (== 6)

Comment: @brianpck Whoops. Yes, you're right. It's O(n^2).

Answer (score 51):

Though the previous answer will give you all pairwise orderings, the example expected result seems to imply that you want all *unordered* pairs.

This can be done with `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Compare to the other result:

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations(x, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import itertools

x = [1,2,3,4]

for each in itertools.permutations(x,2):
    print(each)
```

Note that itertools is a generator object, meaning you need to iterate through it to get all you want. The '2' is optional, but it tells the function what's the number per combination you want.

[You can read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Edited:

As ForceBru said in the comment, you can unpack the generator to print, skipping the for loop together But I would still iterate through it as you might not know how big the generated object will be:

```
print(*itertools.permutations(x, 2))
```

Comment: One can do `print(*itertools.permutations(x, 2))` in Python 3.x, which is even shorter.

Comment: @ForceBru Good point, unpacking it, I guess I can add it to the answer too, but I was thinking that there must be a reason why OP needs to generate these (thinking maybe OP will use them in another function call or something)

Comment: @ForceBru `permutations` returns an iterator, but I'm pretty sure that unpacking it is going to create a (potentially large) object which might actually slow the whole process down (esp. if swapping becomes required).

Comment: @lungj Given that this is a standard library solution, I really don't expect you're going to get better performance using another method.

Comment: Except that this does not give the desired output. You need `itertools.combinations` instead.

Comment: @brianpck I'm just comparing the performance of two methods, both using the built-in (i.e., I'm not suggesting rolling-our-own). I ran a benchmark with `timeit` with the for-loop and compared it to the tuple-unpacking version with a no-op for both (since I'm guessing OP wasn't simply going to print out every single value). On a list created using `x = list(range(5000))`, the tuple-unpacked version runs 3x slower on my computer than the non-unpacked version. However, for small lists, the overhead from calling my no-op function outweighed the cost of allocating memory for the entire tuple.

Comment: @lungj Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment and thought you were talking about the efficiency of `permutations` itself, not the unpacking. My bad.