# Mapping z's in numpy array A = [[x0, y0, z0], [x1, y1, z1]] for 3rd column of array B = [[x1, y1, ?], [x0, y0, ?]] based off matching (x,y)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, label

I have a numpy array `T` whose rows have the following column structure: `[x, y, value]`, where x, y, value are integers. A sample `T` array would look like:

```
[[1, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 7]]
```

This data comes from a model where the third column specifies the value of a variable for the tuple `(x, y)`. In the model, this tuple corresponds to a label for the value. For example, my label `T_10` (subscript `10`) has value `4`, `T_02` has value `3` and `T_12` has value `7`.

Now, I want to swap a pair of labels. For example, I want to replace all labels `2` with `1` (and vice versa), to get `T_20`, `T_01` and `T_21` for the previous examples respectively. So, this new data is

```
U = [[2, 0, ?],
     [0, 1, ?],
     [2, 1, ?]]
```

My issue is that I do not know how to make my new data look like this:

```
U = [[2, 0, -3]
     [0, 1, -4],
     [2, 1, -7]]
```

This new data should follow **two rules**:

**First**, it should correctly identify the row of `T` whose first and second columns `(x, y)` are the same as the new `(x, y)` in `U`. For each row of `U`, if the ordered pair `(x, y) = (x, y)` of `T`, then the appropriate '?' value  in the third column of `U` should be the corresponding value in `T`.

**Second**: If, on the other hand, `(x, y)` of `U = (y, x)` of `T`, then it should be the negative of the corresponding `value`.

My attempt involved first extracting the columns of `T`, and then swapping the pair of labels using the following function:

```
def swap_indices(a, pair):
    for n, i in enumerate(a):
        if i == pair[0]: # check whether a0's element is = swap element 1
            a[n] = pair[1]
        elif i == pair[1]: 
            a[n] = pair[0]
    return a
```

For example, I will swap label `0` with `1` and vice versa for column `x` and column `y` using:

```
pair = (0, 1)
a0 = swap_indices(T[:,0], pair) # column x  
a1 = swap_indices(T[:,1], pair) # column y
```

Then I iterate over the number of rows of `T`; `num_rows_of_T`:

```
for k in range(num_rows_of_T):
    temp = np.where((T[k, 0] == a0[k]) & (T[k, 1] == a1[k]) | ((T[k, 0] == a1[k]) & (T[k, 1] == a0[k])))
```

Above, I am trying to get the index of the row where either `(x, y)` of `U` = `(x, y)` of `T`, or `(x, y)` of `U = (y, x)` of `T`. However this is where I get stuck. I don't think the above is correct. Also, this approach will not let me apply the **second rule** where I take the negative of the value of `T` if `(x, y) = (y, x)`. I also tried using `set()` for starters (to get an unordered pair), but I cannot correctly find the corresponding value of `T` even then.

Basically, I want to find the `value`s of `T` that match with the new labels in `U`. My data is nice, in that there may only exist one possible set of coordinates, and that there is always a bijective mapping between the `(x,y)` of `T` and `U` (given my two rules).

Any advice?
Please help edit the question as necessary. It was very difficult for me to ask.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

# swap index labels if match swap pair
def swap_indices(a, pair):
    for n, i in enumerate(a):
        if i == pair[0]: # check whether a0's element is = swap element 1
            a[n] = pair[1]
        elif i == pair[1]: 
            a[n] = pair[0]
    return a
        
def find_valid_swaps(The1 = np.array([1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1]), headers = np.array(['10', '20', '21', '30', '31', '32'])):
 
    num_indices = len(The1)
    T = np.zeros((num_indices,3)); U = T;
    
    # match format given for T in question
    for i in range(num_indices):
        T[i,:] = [int(list(headers[i])[0]), int(list(headers[i])[1]), The1[i]]
    
    pair = (0, 1) # label pair to swap
    a0 = swap_indices(T[:, 0], pair) # column 0 of U
    a1 = swap_indices(T[:, 1], pair) # column 1 of U
    
    # try to extract correct 'value' from T based on new labels in U
    for k in range(num_indices):
        temp = np.where((T[k, 0] == a0[k]) & (T[k, 1] == a1[k]) | ((T[k, 0] == a1[k]) & (T[k, 1] == a0[k])))
        print("temp",temp[0][0])
        U[k, :] = [a0[k], a1[k], T[temp[0][0], 2]] # here, I would finally create the new U matrix, applying both rules

    print(U)

find_valid_swaps()
```

More involved example using @MadPhysicist 's answer:

```
# swap index labels if match swap pair
def swap_indices(a, pair):
    for n, i in enumerate(a):
        if i == pair[0]: # check whether a0's element is = swap element 1
            a[n] = pair[1]
        elif i == pair[1]: 
            a[n] = pair[0]
    return a
    
def key(arr, m):
    return arr[:, 0] * m + arr[:, 1]
    
def find_valid_swaps(Thetas1 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1]), Thetas2 = np.array([1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1]), num_bands = 4, headers = np.array(['10', '20', '21', '30', '31', '32'])):
    
    import itertools # for permutations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092474/get-all-pairwise-combinations-from-a-list
    
    if (Thetas1==Thetas2).all():
        print("Warning: Input sets of indices are equal to each other. Will check other possible permutations regardless.")
    else: 
        print("Input sets of indices are unique. Will proceed checking other viable permutations.")

    num_indices = len(Thetas1)
    
    T = np.zeros((num_indices,3))
    U = np.zeros((num_indices,3))
    
    for i in range(num_indices):
        T[i,:] = [int(list(headers[i])[0]), int(list(headers[i])[1]), Thetas2[i]]
    
    print("input T")
    print(T)
    
    pair = (2,3)
    a0 = swap_indices(T[:,0], pair) # column 1  
    a1 = swap_indices(T[:,1], pair) # column 2 
    
    
    for k in range(num_indices):
        U[k, :] = [a0[k], a1[k], 0] 

    # below code due to @MadPhysicist from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223782/mapping-zs-in-numpy-array-a-x0-y0-z0-x1-y1-z1-for-3rd-column-of-ar/67235030?noredirect=1#67235030
    
    y_max = T[:, 1].max() + 1
    Tkey = key(T, y_max)
    s = np.argsort(Tkey)

    Ukey = key(U, y_max)
    i = np.searchsorted(Tkey, Ukey, sorter=s)
    i[i == len(i)] -= 1  # cleanup indices that won't match anyway
    mask = (Ukey == Tkey[s[i]])

    U2key = key(U[~mask, 1::-1], y_max)
    j = np.searchsorted(Tkey, U2key, sorter=s)
   
    U[mask, -1] = T[s[i[mask]], -1]
    U[~mask, -1] = -T[s[j], -1]
    
    print("reordered U")
    print(U)
```

The above gives output:

```
input T
[[ 1.,  0.,  1.]
 [ 2.,  0.,  0.]
 [ 2.,  1., -1.]
 [ 3.,  0.,  1.]
 [ 3.,  1.,  0.]
 [ 3.,  2.,  1.]]
reordered U
[[ 1.,  0.,  1.]
 [ 3.,  0.,  0.]
 [ 3.,  1., -1.]
 [ 2.,  0.,  1.]
 [ 2.,  1.,  0.]
 [ 2.,  3.,  1.]]
```

Comment: SO does not support tex formatting. Please format as code and use python-like pseudo-code if you must.

Comment: The question is fairly clear.

Comment: I guess you already have `T` and first 2 columns of `U`, and just want to execute a search for the rows `U` in `T` to find corresponding rows. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have edited the question accordingly and provided a minimal working example. @swag2198 yes, you are correct. Such a search would result in only one direct find (up to application of the second rule).

Comment: Could you add commas to the sample arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boil your algorithm down to three big steps:

1. Sort Txy
2. Binary search for Uxy in Txy
3. Binary search for remaining Uyx in Txy

Combining the result is clearly pretty trivial. The whole operation should be quite doable in `O(N log N)` time because that's how long each step takes.

Since `np.searchsorted` is the prime candidate for steps 2 and 3, let's say that you can turn the first two columns into a unique key. For example, let's say that `y <= y_max` in all cases, and that `y_max` has a sane bound such that `x * y_max + y <= 2**32-1` for all `x`. You can play with using `np.int64` or using `x_max` instead of `y_max` at your leisure.

So now you do:

```
def key(arr, m):
    return arr[:, 0] * m + arr[:, 1]

y_max = T[:, :1].max(None) + 1
Tkey = key(T, y_max)
s = np.argsort(Tkey)
```

To find which elements of `U` match:

```
Ukey = key(U, y_max)
i = np.searchsorted(Tkey, Ukey, sorter=s)
i[i == len(i)] -= 1  # cleanup indices that won't match anyway
mask = (Ukey == Tkey[s[i]])
```

Now find the reverse index.

```
U2key = key(U[~mask, 1::-1], y_max)
j = np.searchsorted(Tkey, U2key, sorter=s)
```

Since the mapping is bijective, this step only searched for elements that are guaranteed to exist, and there's no need to verify the indices.

Now you can combine the indices. If `U` doesn't already have a third column, add one:

```
U = np.concatenate((U, np.empty_like(T[:, :1])), axis=1)
```

Using the indices we computed, extract the elements of `Tsort` that you want:

```
U[mask, -1] = T[s[i[mask]], -1]
U[~mask, -1] = -T[s[j], -1]
```

Now if you can't get a mapping like `key` working, things can be a bit more complicated. If nothing else works, first try

```
def key(arr):
    return arr[:, 0] + 1j * arr[:, 1]
```

The complex values will only be used as sort keys and nothing else. If that fails, you may have to define a structured datatype and view your array through that to get the search working. You can of course implement a hierarchical search, but I feel that that's out of scope here.

---

Here is a complete toy example based off your `T`, with a slightly modified `U` that shows both positive and negative numbers in the last column:

```
>>> T = np.array([[1, 0, 4],
                  [0, 2, 3],
                  [1, 2, 7]])
>>> U = np.array([[2, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0],
                  [2, 0, 0]])
>>> def key(arr, m):
...     return arr[:, 0] * m + arr[:, 1]

>>> y_max = T[:, :1].max(None) + 1
>>> Tkey = key(T, y_max)
>>> s = np.argsort(Tkey)

>>> Ukey = key(U, y_max)
>>> i = np.searchsorted(Tkey, Ukey, sorter=s)
>>> i[i == len(i)] -= 1  # cleanup indices that won't match anyway
>>> mask = (Ukey == Tkey[s[i]])

>>> U2key = key(U[~mask, 1::-1], y_max)
>>> j = np.searchsorted(Tkey, U2key, sorter=s)

>>> U[mask, -1] = T[s[i[mask]], -1]
>>> U[~mask, -1] = -T[s[j], -1]
>>> print(U)
[[ 2  1 -7]
 [ 1  0  4]
 [ 2  0 -3]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write all this! I am trying to understand your code (there are a few commands that are new to me). One thing I have trouble following is the definition of Tsort (as opposed to T). I figured T and U were defined as in my example. Would you mind clarifying? Thanks again!

Comment: Good catch. `Tsort` is a holdover from a previous edit that is actually the thing that made me introduce `Tkey` and `s` instead of sorting `T` directly. I fixed it now

Comment: @TribalChief. I've added a small example for you to play with (and to help me make sure that I posted working code :).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and for the example! I tried it with data that looks more like what I will work with (added it to the end of the question). However, the sorting doesn't seem to work. I tried sorting by x_max, but even then, I seemed to miss it. Any advice?

Comment: @TribalChief. Which sorting didn't work? How did it not work?

Comment: The output U matrix has the same 3rd column as the input T matrix (I just pasted the output from my run at the end of the question). It doesn't make sense because my example is very much like yours (except larger). However, it seems as if the indices called towards the end don't return anything...

Comment: @TribalChief. I screwed up the index somewhere. Gimme a bit and I'll figure it out. Concept is sound though

Comment: @TribalChief. Fixed. Take a look at the new definition of `y_max`. I was implicitly relying on `y.max() > x.max()`. Now, I just take the max of both columns, and voila, all keys are unique again.

Comment: It works, thank you. It seems as if there is something wrong about my input arrays. But if I type them directly, it works just fine - so, I'll just have to figure that out. Thank you; I would not have even thought of the algorithm you did.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I learned this by watching masters like Divakar

Comment: oof. Hope you get some sleep soon. Do you know why it works if I define T and U explicitly as in your example, but not when I define them manually like in my code? The arrays are the same, and I tried converting all to float. It's bizarre.

Comment: Did you update `y_max = T[:, 1].max() + 1` to `y_max = T[:, :1].max(None) + 1`? It even messed me up because I have it in two places, updated one, but kept copying the code from the other.

Comment: I did, but I think it seems like an issue of how I construct the arrays for T and U. If I leave everything else the same, and just change how I get T and U, the answer differs. But I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: It worked after I treated the data as Python lists until I actually got to your code (at which point I convert them to Numpy arrays). Thanks again!